# New line (\n) character is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had done creating a multi-line sentenced value for a button by using the following code,

```
$('input[type=button]').val('Carriage\nreturn');
```

This code works perfectly well in all browsers except IE. What is the reason.? and How can we fix it.?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjf4ctjg/7/)

Comment: Which IE version are you talking about?

Comment: @Java_User I did a test on IE 9 and 10..

Comment: Hmm. May be. I didn't tried it either as I'm not using IE anymore.

Comment: @JLRishe Yeah that's weird. How can we fix it.? i did little bit of research before posting a question here.. but i did not find a relevant information more clearly.

Comment: use a [`button`](http://jsbin.com/vusoninexega/1/).

Comment: @Yoshi Great fix.. i tested it on my side.. no issues.. http://jsfiddle.net/vjf4ctjg/11/

Comment: @Yoshi Post it as an answer, so that future visitors might get a solution from that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)-element which can contain arbitrary* html:

```
<button type="submit|reset|button:default">
  Carriage<br>
  return
</button>
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/vusoninexega/1/

<sub>*: Not really, but ["Phrasing Content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) at least.</sub>